# gsutil: Argument list too long

Tags: bash, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to upload many thousands of files to Google Cloud Storage, with the following command:

```
gsutil -m cp *.json gs://mybucket/mydir
```

But I get this error:

```
-bash: Argument list too long
```

What is the best way to handle this? I can obviously write a bash script to iterate over different numbers:

```
gsutil -m cp 92*.json gs://mybucket/mydir
gsutil -m cp 93*.json gs://mybucket/mydir
gsutil -m cp ...*.json gs://mybucket/mydir
```

But the problem is that I don't know in advance what my filenames are going to be, so writing that command isn't trivial.

Is there either a way to handle this with `gsutil` natively (I don't think so, [from the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)), or a way to handle this in bash where I can list say 10,000 files at a time, then pipe them to the `gsutil` command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Eric's answer should work, but another option would be to rely on gsutil's built-in wildcarding, by quoting the wildcard expression:

```
gsutil -m cp "*.json" gs://mybucket/mydir
```

To explain more: The "Argument list too long" error is coming from the shell, which has a limited size buffer for expanded wildcards. By quoting the wildcard you prevent the shell from expanding the wildcard and instead the shell passes that literal string to gsutil. gsutil then expands the wildcard in a streaming fashion, i.e., expanding it while performing the operations, so it never needs to buffer an unbounded amount of expanded text. As a result you can use gsutil wildcards over arbitrarily large expressions. The same is true when using gsutil wildcards over object names, so for example this would work:

```
gsutil -m cp "gs://my-bucket1/*" gs://my-bucket2
```

even if there are a billion objects at the top-level of gs://my-bucket1.

Comment: As good practice, you should still quote `gs://my-bucket1/*`. The shell will still treat that string as a pattern to match, and although it will almost certainly fail to match anything, it is possible to set a shell option to treat non-matching patterns as an error rather than as a literal string.

Comment: Thanks chepner - I added quotes to my answer per your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, saved me some time!

Answer (score 3):

If your filenames are safe from newlines you could use `gsutil cp`'s ability to read from `stdin` like

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.json' | gsutil -m cp -I gs://mybucket/mydir
```

or if you're not sure if your names are safe and your `find` and `xargs` support it you could do

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.json' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} gsutil -m cp {} gs://mybucket/mydir
```

Comment: The last example would be simpler as `find ... -exec gsutil -m cp {} gs://mybucket/mydir \;`. (In either case, I think `-m` is unnecessary, since you are only passing a single file/URL to each instance of `gsutil`.)

Comment: @chepner does `xargs` then spawn a new instance of `gsutil` for each file if the argument isn't at the end as with `-exec` using `\;` instead of `+`?  Your version of the `find` command would be portable at least though

Comment: @chepner yup, reading the man page does indeed confirm as you said, `-I` implies `-L 1`

Comment: I think there are ways of using `xargs` to similarly batch like `-exec ... +`, but I think the issue here is that `gsutil` either takes a pattern or a single file. I didn't see a way to write something like `-exec cp -T src_dir {} +` like you could with GNU `cp`.

Comment: @chepner I worked out a way to do it, shame I didn't refresh the page before posting!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you could do it, using `xargs` to limit the number of files that are passed to `gsutil` at once. Null bytes are used to prevent problems with spaces in or newlines in the filenames.

```
printf '%s\0' *.json | xargs -0 sh -c 'copy_all () { 
    gsutil -m cp "$@" gs://mybucket/mydir
}
copy_all "$@"'
```

Here we define a function which is used to put the file arguments in the right place in the `gsutil` command. This whole process should happen the minimum number of times required to process all arguments, passing the maximum number of filename arguments possible each time.

Alternatively you can define the function separately and then `export` it (this is bash-specific):

```
copy_all () { 
    gsutil -m cp "$@" gs://mybucket/mydir
}
printf '%s\0' *.json | xargs -0 bash -c 'export -f copy_all; copy_all "$@"'
```